# Jersey RESTful POST operation gets null values of @PathParam and does not INSERT expected values in MySQL

Tags: rest, post, jersey-2.0, mysql-error-1064

My RESTful POST operation is as follows

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Path("/dbuser")
public class DBUserRestServices extends DbConnectionDAO{


@POST
    @Path("/postuser1")  //Problem here???
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Transactional
    public Response userPOSTOperation( @PathParam("userid") int userid,@PathParam("username") String username,
            @PathParam("password") String password) throws SQLException{
    
        UserObject userobj = new UserObject(userid, username, password);
        username= userobj.getUsername();
        password= userobj.getPassword();
        System.out.println("UserName " + username + "\t\t"+ "Password :" + password);   
        
        dbConnection = new DbConnectionDAO();
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) values ('" +"username" +"',"+ "'password" +"')";
        
        System.out.println("Query executed : " + sqlQuery );

        try{
            connection = DbConnectionDAO.setDBConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            numRowsChanged = statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
            
            System.out.println("numRowsChanged : " + numRowsChanged );
            if (numRowsChanged<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Oops!! The insertion operation failed");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The POST operation with username = " + username + ", password "+ password+" has been completed");
            }
        
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Response.ok().build();

    }


}

//
// The DbConnectionDAO.java file is 

public class DbConnectionDAO {

    public static Connection connection;
    public static Statement statement;
    public static PreparedStatement pst;
    public static ResultSet rs = null;
    private static String sqlQuery = null;

    static int numRowsChanged = 0;

    public static Connection setDBConnection() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

            //  Connection connection = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "password");
            if (connection != null) {
                // System.out.println("Connected to the Database...");
            }

            return connection;
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }


// The UserObject.java file is 

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "userObject")
public class UserObject {
    private int userid;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    
      public UserObject(){}

       public UserObject(int userid, String username, String password){
          this.userid = userid;
          this.username = username;
          this.password = password;
       }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    @XmlElement
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @XmlElement
    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    
    @XmlElement
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

When I give the following command in Postman: `http://localhost:8080/iAdjuster/restapi/dbuser/postuser1/?username=John&password=Michael`

it shows the following Console output:

```
UserName null       Password :null
Query executed : INSERT INTO user (username, password) values ('username','password')
numRowsChanged : 1
The POST operation with username = null, password null has been completed
```

However, the MySQL database shows a successful INSERtion with values 'username' and 'password' in the username and password fields with an auto increment userid.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code -

1. You are using `POST` method, but your logic is not related to `POST` data processing. So, Identify and decide whether you want to send `GET` request or `POST` request. If you want to send all data in request `URI`, there is no point of using `POST` method, instead you should use `GET` method.
2. In your calling command, you are passing 'username' and 'password' as query parameter and in the REST API, you are receiving them as Path parameters. There is a difference between path parameters and query parameters. Also, you haven't defined 'username' and 'password' in `@Path` annotation. That is why, they are null.

Your method declaration should look like below -

```
@POST
@Path("/{userid}/{username}/{password}") 
@Transactional
public Response userPOSTOperation( @PathParam("userid") int userid,@PathParam("username") String username,
        @PathParam("password") String password) throws SQLException{
```

And you should be able to send `POST` request with URI -

```
http://localhost:8080/iAdjuster/restapi/dbuser/userId/John/Michael
```

3. Also, your SQL query is wrong. SQL query should be -

   String sqlQuery =  "INSERT INTO user (username, password) values ('" +username +"','"+ password +"')";